# Hide name between messages from same person in Pidgin

Tags: instant-messaging, pidgin

When you have a conversation in Pidgin, the name of each person is shown in front of each message. I found a plugin (New Line) that prepends a newline after the name of the person, which makes it more clearer according to me (because of variable width buddy names).

Now I'm thinking it would be very nice if the name wouldn't be shown before each message, but only the first message of one person in a row.

So as an example

Now:

```
(01:58:22 PM) John:
Hi
(01:58:24 PM) John:
How are you doing?
(01:58:30 PM) David:
I'm fine
(01:58:32 PM) David:
How are you?
(01:58:40 PM) John:
Fine, fine, fine
```

Desired:

```
(01:58:22 PM) John:
H
How are you doing?
(01:58:30 PM) David:
I'm fine
How are you?
(01:58:40 PM) John:
Fine, fine, fine
```

Comment: Hey. Any luck finding a way to get that? I'm after the exact same thing.

Comment: Nope, sorry man