# How not to show user name beside each consecutive message

Tags: pidgin, google-talk

After years on GTalk, I recently switched to Pidgin for my IM needs.
Almost all is ok with me, though there's on thing that bugs me. It shows the name of the author beside each consecutive message.

e.g.

```
joce: Hey
joce: Long time no see!
joce: How are you?
Bob: Hey!
Bob: Indeed!
```

Instead of (as it is in GTalk):

```
joce: Hey
 Long time no see!
 How are you?
bob: Hey!
 Indeed!
```

Is there a setting that I've missed or a plugin that could do that for me?

Comment: Pleas don't create a [duplicate question](http://superuser.com/questions/454995/hide-name-between-messages-from-same-person-in-pidgin?rq=1), instead, consider [placing a bounty](http://superuser.com/help/bounty) on the existing one.

Comment: Hum yeah. Placing a bounty. With my *incredible* score of 163. That will happen. :-/

Comment: You only need 75 rep to place a bounty, and you can give as little as 50 away. http://superuser.com/help/privileges/set-bounties :)